# Private Beta Evaluation — Our private beta clashed with SIGGRAPH 2015

Tags: discussion

[SIGGRAPH 2015](http://s2015.siggraph.org/) was from 9th to 13th August. These 5 days plus travel time to and from clashed with our private beta starting from 4th August. This drained the site of some of its experts for a week. At least one expert was affected by this, as can be seen from [this comment](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-subdivision-algorithm-advances-have-occurred-since-catmull-clark#comment212_15):

> Sorry, I'm at SIGGRAPH and have absolutely no free time (except to write this comment). Someone else should feel free to write an answer using the links in my comments. –  Rahul

There is no particular action required from this meta post. It serves two purposes:

1. A way of smiling nicely at Stack Exchange staff to say "What we're achieving here is *despite* having this clash with the graphics conference.
2. A way of saying thank you to everyone contributing and to say "Keep up the good work".

**It would be interesting to have an idea of how many people from this private beta were at SIGGRAPH and therefore unable to spare time for the private beta for that week.**

If it's just the one person then my thank you to everyone still stands...

Comment: Even though I was not physically at siggraph (sigh), during and right after siggraph my free time is almost completely consumed reading/studying/digesting the content produced by the conference. I am sure is the same for other people too.

Comment: @cifz We are deciding now if this was a determining factor. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The site was off to a strong start, but participation fell off a cliff about a week in. Was it the SIGGRAPH conference? Or maybe there are other SE sites these question can be asked.

[**Apparently this is a duplicate**](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17837/apparently-this-is-a-duplicate)

**We extended the private beta until next week to see if usage picks up somewhat**, or if the folks building this site simply lost interested half way in.

(Housekeeping note: There was a small hiccup on Friday 21 Aug, afternoon NYC time, in which we shut down this site prematurely by accident. As you can see, it has since been restored. The site was only down for about 2 hours.)

Comment: Thanks for featuring this question and for giving some additional time. The linked post is very interesting, particularly reading it with our particular site in mind. As much as I'm hoping, I can't judge yet whether we're ready for public beta, but I have some thoughts. Unless it would be better as a separate meta post I'll post them as an answer here once I've gathered them together.

Comment: Trichoplax, I will leave that to you. If you feel your assertions might lead to other members "answering" your premise, write it for them and create a new meta post.

Comment: Yes I would like to see other people's views, so I've [posted as a separate question](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/115/should-computer-graphics-be-a-separate-stack-exchange-site).

Comment: Btw this site hasn't questions like "how can i install winzip", so why the "number" is so important? I ask this because i think that this site rate of questions will not be so high in the future, but ATM it's the best place on the internet you can ask something.

Comment: @psicomante maybe you should ask so we can close it :p

Comment: @psicomante I see your point - there will be far more people on the internet asking for basic installation instructions, and our site can't compete with that on number of questions, but for our smaller number of questions I agree we are providing better answers than elsewhere.

Comment: @trichoplax yep, my point was that: although our number of Q/A is lower than others sites, we offer better answers than elsewhere. Moreover questions on this site are more complex, and they require more time to be correctly answered. 
If this is true, the value of one of our question is greater than a the value of a queustion like "what is the best software for...".

Comment: @jojaa lol! i hope that a question like that will ne be asked here! :D No ok, i could ask, "what is the best live editor for GLSL" :D